# trying to login instagram

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried this to log in to intagram but it worked once but not anymore .
and I tried adding the encrypted pass but also it didn't work
and also it didn't work for the first page of instagram
'https://www.instagram.com' instead of the link

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

payload = {
    'username': 'USERNAME',
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:"PASSWORD"',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken":csrf
    })
```

Comment: What about `selenium`? Did you try doing the same with `selenium`?

Comment: selenium actually drives the browser and it doesn't work with minimizing the browser ,  I went to get the data without opening the browser

Comment: You can use selenium without opening the browser.

Comment: any tutorial suggestion ?